# Mysql - select a random row from one table and join it to three rows in another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

One is holding the titles of games.
Another is holding the rankings for the users playing those games.

```
SELECT r.game, u.username, r.userid, r.points
FROM tbl_game g
INNER JOIN tbl_ranking r ON r.game = g.name
INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON u.id = r.userid
WHERE g.active = '1'
AND r.type = '1'
ORDER BY rand( ) , r.points
LIMIT 3
```

This is my attempt.

What I am trying to do is select a random row from the tbl_game table and then join it to the three best users in the tbl_ranking table.

For example, if Madden was randomly selected, it would find the best 3 users for that game and return them.

Any idea how I can do this in one query?
Is it possible?

Thanks

EDIT
I have now attempted what I think is the correct way to do this.
I have syntax errors, if someone could help?

```
SELECT userid, points(
     SELECT name
     FROM tbl_game
     WHERE active = '1'
     ORDER BY rand( )
     LIMIT 1
     ) AS randgame
FROM tbl_ranking
WHERE TYPE = '1'
AND game = randgame
ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3
```

EDIT...need to add more into the query

There is the need to select Xbox 360 or Playstation 3 from tbl_format and ensure only users on either are compared.

```
SELECT r.game, u.username, r.userid, r.points
FROM tbl_ranking r
INNER JOIN tbl_users u ON u.id = r.userid
WHERE r.type = '1'
AND r.game = (
       SELECT name
       FROM tbl_game
       WHERE active = '1'
       ORDER BY rand( )
       LIMIT 1 )
AND u.format = (
       SELECT format
       FROM tbl_format
       WHERE active = '1'
       ORDER BY rand( )
       LIMIT 1 )
ORDER BY r.points DESC
LIMIT 3
```

The idea is that you join to the user table where they have a field `format` and they either are ps3 or xbox360. So when you run the query you select either ps3 or xbox360 from the tbl_format table, compare that to the usernames and select three users on one console or the other from a randomly selected game!

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your second query seems correct. Have you tried it?

Comment: Yeah but it didn't work, a better answer was provided. But I have other things that need adding to the query. My third one is close to what I am after, with an explanation afterwards. Can you help?

Comment: Do you want results for both XBox360 and PS3, or just one or the other?

Comment: One or the other. So again, pick it randomly.

Comment: If that's the case, then I'm about 90% certain your third query will work.  If it's not, then we'll need more information, like error messages, actual vs expected results, etc.

Comment: It's mixing users from PS3 and Xbox360! Reading it back, it should work. There are no error messages. Literally just isn't selecting one format and sticking to it!

Comment: @Luke: I meant the last (3rd) query, not second. If it doesn't show what you want, provide the tables` fields. I would expect the `format` field to be in the `game` table and not in the `user` table. I suppose a game can be either for Xbox or Playstation and not a user.

Comment: The format is stored in the user table. So I am attempting to select a random game and find the rankings for that. But only find users that are on either ps3 or xbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT userid, points
FROM tbl_ranking
WHERE TYPE = '1'
AND game = (SELECT name
     FROM tbl_game
     WHERE active = '1'
     ORDER BY rand( )
     LIMIT 1
     )
ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 3
```

I think this is what you want

Comment: Worked perfectly, but I need to add a bit more into it that I forgot about. I'll edit the question again and see if you can help me. I'll tick this regardless as it was the answer for my original question!

Answer (score 0):

start with `SELECT userid, points,`  (add a comma after points).